# Jmeter jdbc results variable to http

Tags: jmeter

So i a using this query
**select  f_authority, username  from account where username like 'jmca_%' and status = 'account.status.active' order by f_principal;**

My data Are :

```
            f_authority username
            1002       jmca_1000
            1003       jmca_1001
            1004       jmca_1002
```

i Want to use every f_authority and useranme in same for each loop in deferent http call..

i am using

```
vars.put("credentials",vars.get("username"));
```

the think is that i cant get f_authority  from for each controller but how i can get username or both variable with beanShell???

[image: for each controller]

[image: BeanShell]

Answer (score 0):

You will get the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) defined as the result of the JDBC Sampler call:

```
f_authority_1=1002
f_authority_2=1003
f_authority_3=1004
f_authority_#=3
username_1=jmca_1000
username_2=jmca_1001
username_3=jmca_1002
username_#=3
```

If you want to iterate both of them in a single ForEach Controller:

1. For `f_authority` just put it into "Input variable prefix" and `Output Variable Name` fields

   [image]
2. For `username` you can use [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) and [__intSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) functions combination

   ```
   ${__V(username_${__intSum(${__jm__ForEach Controller__idx},1,)},)}
   ```

   [image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)